# How call customview on action of button?

Tags: iphone, uipickerview, toolbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have create a demo project in which i have add button. On button action i am calling a custom view. On that custom view i have add a picker view, a toolbar and bar button. On action of button i am calling that custom view. I have used this code...

```
-(IBAction)Picker{

mpv_object  = [[MyPickerView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyPickerView" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:mpv_object];
[mpv_object release];
```

}

But i give error which i given below...

> 2011-09-26 09:49:00.236 Web[440:207] -[MyPickerView initWithNibName:bundle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b4dcb0
>   2011-09-26 09:49:00.287 Web[440:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyPickerView initWithNibName:bundle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b4dcb0'
>   *** Call stack at first throw:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x00daebe9 **exceptionPreprocess + 185
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00f035c2 objc_exception_throw + 47
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x00db06fb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
>       3   CoreFoundation                      0x00d20366 __*forwarding*** + 966
>       4   CoreFoundation                      0x00d1ff22 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
>       5   Web                                 0x0000223a -[WebViewController Picker] + 102
>       6   UIKit                               0x002b7a6e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
>       7   UIKit                               0x003461b5 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
>       8   UIKit                               0x00348647 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
>       9   UIKit                               0x003471f4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
>       10  UIKit                               0x002dc0d1 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
>       11  UIKit                               0x002bd37a -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
>       12  UIKit                               0x002c2732 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
>       13  GraphicsServices                    0x016e4a36 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
>       14  CoreFoundation                      0x00d90064 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 52
>       15  CoreFoundation                      0x00cf06f7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
>       16  CoreFoundation                      0x00ced983 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
>       17  CoreFoundation                      0x00ced240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
>       18  CoreFoundation                      0x00ced161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
>       19  GraphicsServices                    0x016e3268 GSEventRunModal + 217
>       20  GraphicsServices                    0x016e332d GSEventRun + 115
>       21  UIKit                               0x002c642e UIApplicationMain + 1160
>       22  Web                                 0x00001f80 main + 102
>       23  Web                                 0x00001f11 start + 53
>   )
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
>    What is error in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like `MyPickerView` is a `UIView` subclass.  `initWithNibName:bundle` is not a method that exists on `UIView` subclasses.  It is a method that exists on `UIViewController` subclasses.  That is what the error message means.

Answer (score 0):

`unrecognized selector sent to instance` suggests that MyPickerView's superclass doesn't know what `initWithNibName:bundle` is, which is because UIView doesn't know that method (it exists in `UIViewController`).

Answer (score 0):

Right way to do this would be something like this

```
UIView *dpView;
NSArray *nibViews;
nibViews =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DatePickerSliderViewNew" owner:self options:nil];
dpView = [ nibViews objectAtIndex: 0];
int outside = CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.bounds);
dpView.frame = CGRectMake(0, outside, 320, 260);
[self.view addSubview:dpView];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
dpView.frame = CGRectMake(0, outside - 260, 320, 260);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: I have pasted the code from my working samples and hence the name of the variables. Hope it is clear that the nib you will create here is named "DatePickerSliderViewNew".